# Rearranging primary keys

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have a PHP page which interacts with this small MySQL database table with a simple structure. `ID`, `Name`, `Address` are the fields. `ID` is the primary key.

```
+------+------------+-------------+
|  ID  |   Name     |   Country   |
|______|____________|_____________|
| E001 |  Stephen   |   America   |
| E002 |  John      |   Britain   |
| E003 |  Kate      |   Canada    |
| E004 |  Carlos    |   Spain     |
| E005 |  James     |   Australia |
|______|____________|_____________|
```

If I remove the record at **E003**, it looks like this.

```
+------+------------+-------------+
|  ID  |   Name     |   Country   |
|______|____________|_____________|
| E001 |  Stephen   |   America   |
| E002 |  John      |   Britain   |
| E004 |  Carlos    |   Spain     |
| E005 |  James     |   Australia |
|______|____________|_____________|
```

A gap appears between **E002** and **E004**.

Is there a way to *fill in* that gap? Like this

```
+------+------------+-------------+
|  ID  |   Name     |   Country   |
|______|____________|_____________|
| E001 |  Stephen   |   America   |
| E002 |  John      |   Britain   |
| E003 |  Carlos    |   Spain     |
| E004 |  James     |   Australia |
|______|____________|_____________|
```

Earlier record which had **E004**, fall into the place of **E003**. Former **E005** gets the number **E004** and so on. Like the records *take a step back*.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: wouldn't that remove the purpose of a primary key when you're moving/renumbering the unique ID of a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to renumber them? The key values shouldn't really matter. If they do (i.e., they are used for outside purposes), consider having the external key be a regular column in the table and let the primary key be an auto-increment integer field. Even if you do this, you still probably shouldn't be renumbering keys. That would mean that all external dependencies would need to be updated as well. There's just not much value in doing it.

But, if you have to...

If the key is auto-increment (which it should be), you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP ID;
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

If it's not, then you can do several things, but the easiest might be to use variables to act as a counter. To make this easier, please don't use a string primary key, but instead use a plain numeric primary key.

```
SET @id = 0;

UPDATE MyTable
SET ID = (@id := @id + 1)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Actually there isn't a strong reason. I just didn't like the key field's values appearing like that. I understand now. I wasn't thinking very deep. Thank you for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In your database table ID is primary key and it is alphanumeric.

I don't think so it is a good way for rearranging primary key in table. All its relation with other table will be messed up.

Try to use numeric primary key instead of string.

If you use numeric primary key, you can rearrange them by dropping and recreating primary key column with auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `ID` field is not an `integer` field you can't do it with just one query and you need to do a loop over all records after the gap and update the ID field.

But a better way might be to change the `ID` filed type to auto increment unsigned integer and then by knowing the last `ID` before the gap equals to `gID` you can do a query like this :

```
UPDATE table_name SET `ID` = (`ID` - 1) WHERE `ID` > gID;
```

Then you just need to update your auto_increment value:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELEC `ID` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Since all the records in your `ID` field have the letter 'E' in common, it might be possible to get rid of this letter and change the field type to an `AUTO INCREMENT UNSIGNED INTEGER`