# How to sort primary keys

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I deleted some of my records from table. Now I want to sort them by id and fill in gaps with existing record. I can share view of data.

I want to lose unnecessary number of id values.

[picture is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MJfBUVUvf_meApnZlGgj0p6M2JWkrkI/view)

[mysql data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvAjR.png)

I tried alter table command but I did not solve or i tried truncate, it is awful`enter code here`

Comment: Why do you want to fill in the gaps?

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about the gaps

Comment: If you really need to do this, here's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470197/rearranging-primary-keys/12470260#12470260